# What is the proper way to define a dynamic ValidateSet in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell 7.1 helper script that I use to copy projects from subversion to my local device. I'd like to make this script easier for me to use by enabling PowerShell to auto-complete parameters into this script. After some research, it looks like I can implement an interface to provide valid parameters via a ValidateSet.

Based on [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#dynamic-validateset-values-using-classes), I attempted to do this like so:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet([ProjectNames])]
    [String]
    $ProjectName,

    #Other params
)

Class ProjectNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
    [string[]] GetValidValues() {
        # logic to return projects here.
    }
}
```

When I run this, it does not auto-complete and I get the following error:

```
❯ Copy-ProjectFromSubversion.ps1 my-project
InvalidOperation: C:\OneDrive\Powershell-Scripts\Copy-ProjectFromSubversion.ps1:4
Line |
   4 |      [ValidateSet([ProjectNames])]
     |      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Unable to find type [ProjectNames].
```

This makes sense since the class isn't defined until after the parameters. So I moved the class above the parameters. Obviously this is a syntax error. So how do I do this? Is it not possible in a simple PowerShell script?

Comment: That's not based of the documentation. Its basically saying, you have to define the Dynamic Parameter using the keyword `DynmaicParam`, which it in itself wil be the parameter displayed. It also goes to say it can change based off previous Parameter selections.

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala. I can see how my question may have been confusing. I'm not asking about dynamic parameters, but rather a dynamic validate set. Dynamic parameters are parameters that are only available under certain conditions. A dynamic validate set is a validate set that is determined at runtime. An example of a dynamic validate set might be the validate set of the path parameter of get-childitem.

Comment: *"Dynamic parameters are parameters that are only available under certain condition"*, can you explain this some more? As far as I'm aware, this isn't true. I use dynamic parameters that include a validation set based of a `Get-ChildItem` instance from multiple folders in a lot of my scripts. Do you mind rephrasing what you're asking and/or, provide an example of what you mean? @Jason

Comment: Hi @AbrahamZinala. Check out this section in the documentation from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#dynamic-parameters

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, to give a specific example: `Get-ChildItem`'s dynamic `-File` and `-Directory` parameters are only available for file-system provider locations (because they only make sense there).

Comment: @Mklement0, maybe I'm misunderstanding the post. Is the question not in regards to setting dynamic validation sets for a parameter? Probably just confusing myself at this point lol

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, yes, the question is about how to dynamically create the set of valid argument values you my pass to a given _static parameter_, which is unrelated to the concept of _dynamic parameters_.

Comment: @mklement0, isn't that the concept of *dynamic parameters*? In the link Jason posted, it shows an example of just that. The runtime defined parameter applies only within the the block of `DynamicParam`, so the Parameter of `-KeyCount` only becomes present if the value passed to `-Path` begins with *"HKLM:\"*. Also, sorry, not trying to argue. Genuinely curious lol

Comment: Jason pointed to that link to make it clear that dynamic parameters indeed are typically only available _situationally_, which my comment re `-File` and `-Directory` was meant to underscore (your earlier comment seemed to dispute that, unlike your most recent one). Here, we're dealing with a _statically_ defined (i.e. _regular_) parameter - which is _always_ available - whose _validation attribute_ happens to use dynamically created validation data.

Comment: Right. My link in the comment section was in response to your question to "explain this some more". In my question, I edited the link I have there to point to the specific section in the documentation I was referring to in my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed, you've hit a catch-22: for the parameter declaration to work during the script-parsing phase, class `[ProjectNames]` must already be defined, yet you're not allowed to place the class definition *before* the parameter declaration.

The closest *approximation* of your intent using a stand-alone script file (`.ps1`) is to use the [`ValidateScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) attribute instead:

```sh
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [ValidateScript(
    { $_ -in (Get-ChildItem -Directory).Name },
    ErrorMessage = 'Please specify the name of a subdirectory in the current directory.'
  )]
  [String] $ProjectName # ...
)
```

**Limitations**:

- **`[ValidateScript]` does not and *cannot* provide tab-completion**: the [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks), `{ ... }`, providing the validation is only expected to return a *Boolean*, and there's no guarantee that a discrete set of values is even involved.
- Similarly, you can't reference the dynamically generated set of valid values (as generated inside the script block) in the `ErrorMessage` property value.

The only way around these limitations would be to *duplicate that part of the script block that calculates the valid values*, but that can become a *maintenance headache*.

**To get tab-completion** you'll have to duplicate the relevant part of the code in an [`[ArgumentCompleter]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) attribute:

```sh
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory)]
  [ValidateScript(
    { $_ -in (Get-ChildItem -Directory).Name },
    ErrorMessage = 'Please specify the name of a subdirectory in the current directory.'
  )]
  [ArgumentCompleter(
    {
      param($cmd, $param, $wordToComplete)
      # This is the duplicated part of the code in the [ValidateScipt] attribute.
      [array] $validValues = (Get-ChildItem -Directory).Name
      $validValues -like "$wordToComplete*"
    }
  )]
  [String] $ProjectName # ...
)
```

Comment: @mklement0 you said this is the closest approximation using a stand-alone script. If we drop the single-script constraint, could one still use a class defined in a separate file (e.g. in a module)?

Comment: @alazyworkaholic, yes, if you use a _module_ that exports _functions_, these functions can be defined using `class` and `enum` definitions that are part of the same module. And, yes, if a script references `class` and `enum` definitions that are _already loaded_ at the time the script is invoked, that works too. Note that if you want to use a module as a source of `class` and `enum` definitions that can be explicitly referenced from _outside_ that module, the importer of the module must use `using module ...` instead of `Import-Module ...`

Answer (score 0):

Answer is correct, but Error Message is introduced in Powershell 6. Also, the reason, I assume, you are getting is because you are using earlier version as well. Powershell 5.1 does not have IValidateSetValuesGenerator (interface).

If you are using 5.1 use the code suggested beside the ErrorMessage. Beside that great example!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).